# Lock free single producer/single consumer circular buffer - Can CPU speculation break the memory barrier logic?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, atomic, lock-free

I have been looking at a lock free single producer/single consumer circular buffer when I thought about speculative execution and its effect on the simple code.

With this implementation, there is only a unique thread which can call the `push()` function and another unique thread which can call the `pop()` function.

Here is the `Producer` code:

```
bool push(const Element& item)
{       
  const auto current_tail = _tail.load(std::memory_order_relaxed);  //(1)
  const auto next_tail = increment(current_tail);

  if(next_tail != _head.load(std::memory_order_acquire))            //(2)               
  {     
    _array[current_tail] = item;                                    //(3)
    _tail.store(next_tail, std::memory_order_release);              //(4)
    return true;
  }
  return false; // full queue
}
```

Here is the `Consumer` code:

```
bool pop(Element& item)
{
  const auto current_head = _head.load(std::memory_order_relaxed);    //(1)
  if(current_head == _tail.load(std::memory_order_acquire))           //(2)
    return false; // empty queue

  item = _array[current_head];                                       //(3)
  _head.store(increment(current_head), std::memory_order_release);   //(4)
  return true;
}
```

**The Question**

What if the `push()` would be compiled as the following function due to speculative execution:

```
bool push(const Element& item)
{       
  const auto current_tail = _tail.load(std::memory_order_relaxed);  // 1
  const auto next_tail = increment(current_tail);

  //The load is performed before the test, it is valid
  const auto head = _head.load(std::memory_order_acquire);         

  //Here is the speculation, the CPU speculate that the test will succeed
  //store due to speculative execution AND it respects the memory order due to read-acquire
  _array[current_tail] = item;                             
  _tail.store(next_tail, std::memory_order_release); 

  //Note that in this case the test checks if you it has to restore the memory back
  if(next_tail == head)//the code was next_tail != _head.load(std::memory_order_acquire)    
  { 
   //We restore the memory back but the pop may have been called before and see an invalid memory
    _array[current_tail - 1] = item;                                 
    _tail.store(next_tail - 1, std::memory_order_release);             
    return true;
  }
  return false; // full queue
}
```

To me, to be perfectly valid the push function should make sure the barrier is issued **after the condition success**:

```
bool push(const Element& item)
{       
  const auto current_tail = _tail.load(std::memory_order_relaxed);  // 1
  const auto next_tail = increment(current_tail);                   
  if(next_tail != _head.load(std::memory_order_relaxed))            // 2               
  { 
    //Here we are sure that nothing can be reordered before the condition
    std::atomic_thread_fence(std::memory_order_acquire);            //2.1
    _array[current_tail] = item;                                    // 3
    _tail.store(next_tail, std::memory_order_release);              // 4
    return true;
  }
  return false; // full queue
}
```

Comment: *Here we are sure that nothing can be reordered before the condition* - no if accept logic from your first example. the both `r1=_head.load(std::memory_order_relaxed)` and `r2=next_tail` can be loaded to cpu registers , then "CPU speculate" 2.1, 3, 4 and only finally `if (r1==r2)` or if this is impossible - your first push also impossible. but i be ask another, more general. are independ from any memory orders, brriers - at all possible speculative execution with *side effect* - are possibe in `if (x) y = a` - execute `y = a` (write to memory with visible side effect) *before*..

Comment: actually check condition `if (x)`

Comment: @RbMm I'm sorry but it is really hard to understand what your answer mean. May you reformulate in plain English?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

re: your proposed reordering: **no, the compiler can't invent writes to atomic variables.**

Runtime speculation also can't invent writes that actually become visible to other threads.  It can put whatever it wants in its own private store buffer, but the correctness of earlier branches must be checked before a store can become visible to other threads.

Normally this works by in-order retirement: an instruction can only retire (become non-speculative) once all previous instructions are retired/non-speculative.  A store can't commit from the store buffer to L1d cache until after the store instruction retires.

---

re: the title: no, speculative execution still has to respect the memory model.  If a CPU wants to speculatively load past an incomplete acquire-load, it can, but only if it *checks* to make sure those load results are still valid when they're "officially" allowed to happen.

x86 CPUs *do* in practice do this, because the strong x86 memory model means that *all* loads are acquire-loads, so any out-of-order loading has to be speculative and rolled back if it's not valid.  (This is why you can get memory-order mis-speculation pipeline nukes.)

---

So asm works the way the ISA rules say it works, and C++ compilers know that.  Compilers use this to implement the C++ memory model on top of the target ISA.

If you do an acquire-load in C++, it really works as an acquire-load.

You can mentally model your logic for possible compile-time + run-time reordering according to the C++ reordering rules as written.  See http://preshing.com/20120913/acquire-and-release-semantics/.

Comment: What really bother me is that with the original code you have no guarantee that the CPU won't **first** perform the load and the barrier **then** check the condition, so the store could still be reordered after the barrier but  before the check.

Comment: what I want to know is how to make sure that the barrier will be issued after the check succeeded

Comment: @Yoo: that would break the memory model, too.  If the check won't succeed, the CPU can't let any other cores see that speculative store.  Or if you're on some crazy architecture where that could happen, the compiler needs to use an instruction-execution barrier instruction to make sure that doesn't happen.  Like x86 `lfence` or PowerPC `isync`.  (Those ISAs aren't "crazy" in this way, but they do have execution-barrier instructions that stop speculation past them.)

Comment: @PeterCordes - *If the check won't succeed, the CPU can't let any other cores see that speculative store* that is what intuitive assume at begin and try say in comment. can say in more general code `if (x) y.store(a)` (no any compiler/hardware barriers and memory orders here) - can we say that `y = a` not possible *before* execute `if (x)` because `y = a` (store for memory) have visible side effect.